# How to filter out unusual names resulted from "os.listdir"

Tags: python, string, unicode

I use `os.listdir(d)` to list all files in a folder. There are some weird names such as

```
['ￚ',
 'ￛ',
 'ￜ',
 '￠',
 '￡',
 '￢',
 '￣',
 '￤',
 '￥',
 '￦',
 '￩',
 '￪',
 '￫',
 '￬',
 '￭',
 '￮',
 '\ufff9',
 '\ufffa',
 '\ufffb',
 '￼']
```

Could you please suggest any idea to filter out them?

Comment: Why filter them? Apparently that directory has some files with weird names in it. Do weird names disqualify those files from whatever processing you want to perform?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I know the content of such files does not satisfy my condition. So I filter them out to save computation.

Comment: How do you know that? Do the files you want to process have names matching some pattern? If so, you might want to use that pattern to perform your filtering.

Comment: If you don't specify criteria for "weird" names, we cannot help you with the code that filters them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could prepare a list of acceptable characters, such as:

```
acceptables = r'[_,.-]'
```

and then see what pathnames are entirely alphanumeric when those characters are removed:

```
import os, re

[x for x in os.listdir('.') if re.sub(acceptables, '',x).isalnum()]
```

Note that the square parenthesis '[ ]' are required to define the set of characters to ignore, they are not part of the set.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a filter on your list, to only authorize common characters.
Something like that:

```
import os
import re
directories = os.listdir('.')

# Before filter
print(directories)

# Filtered
d = list(filter(lambda x: re.match("[a-zA-Z\d\_\-]+", x), directories))
print(d)

Output: 
Before filter: ['main.py', '￥']
Filtered: ['main.py']
```